# How to install plumbum on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, metapackages

I want to install plumbum on my laptop.

However when I am trying to install it, it is removing some important packages

[image]

Comment: This image shows the message box that displays when I try to install plumbum from ubuntu software center

Comment: The packages are absolutely irrelevant in the sense all metapackages are.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-get install -sf python-plumbum python3-plumbum`? Thanks.

Comment: file:///home/patrick/Pictures/Plumbum1.png
file:///home/patrick/Pictures/Plumbum2.png   This is the out put of apt-get install -sf python-plumbum python3-plumbum

Answer (score 0):

As Ubuntu 16.04 comes with plumbum incoporated inside it, you just need to type `pip install plumbum` in the terminal and press enter. Make sure you are connected to the internet when you do this.